# How to list all the folders that have a subfolder with a specific name inside them using CLI Bash

Tags: command-line, bash

I would like to use cli to list all the folders in my Documents directory that have a subfolder called "images" is there any way to list them easily?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using GNU `find`:

```
find ~/Documents/ -type d -name images -printf '%h\n'
```

From the `-printf` section of `man find`:

```
          %h     Leading directories of file's name (all but the last ele‐
                 ment).  If the file name contains no slashes (since it is
                 in the current directory) the  %h  specifier  expands  to
                 `.'.
```